# JQuery - Get attribute of higher-level item

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the ID of `item1` but it does not return the ID in the code below.  Is there a ways to get the ID of a higher-level function?

I assume that the code is trying to get the ID of `popup` but that is both not needed and does not exist.  Can I get the higher-level function's ID or can I pass it down to the lower function as a parameter?

```
$(".item1").live ("click" ,function(){
    $('.popup_pre_loading').css('display','none');
        $('.popup').fadeIn( 800, function(){
        alert((this).attr('id'));//need this for URL param
      });
      return false;
});
```

Please note that this code works when the the alert box is directly within the `item`'s function.

Comment: `.css('display','none')` === `.hide()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just store a reference to `this` in the outer function, and refer to it in the inner function.

```
$(".item1").live ("click" ,function() {
    var self = this;
    $('.popup_pre_loading').css('display','none');
    $('.popup').fadeIn( 800, function(){
        alert(self.id);
    });
    return false;
});
```

Note that you don't need `$(self).attr('id')` - just `self.id` will do !

Answer (score 3):

Based on your understanding that it works when it is directly in the `item`'s function, I'm guessing you need it within the `fadeIn` function. The simplest way to do that would be to assign it to a variable in the `click` function, and use that variable in the `fadeIn` function.

```
$(".item1").live ("click" ,function(){
    var item1id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.popup_pre_loading').css('display','none');
        $('.popup').fadeIn( 800, function(){
        alert(item1id); //need this for URL param
      });
      return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".item1").live ("click" ,function(){
    var $item1 = $(this);
    $('.popup_pre_loading').css('display','none');
    $('.popup').fadeIn( 800, function(){
        alert((this).attr('id'));//need this for URL param
        alert($item1.attr('id'));
      });
      return false;
});
```

Comment: This won't work. `this` is **not** a jQuery object, it's an actual DOM element, so you can't call jQuery functions on it (you also shouldn't call the variable `$item1`). Also, absolutely no reason to use `.attr()` to get the ID, just use `item1.id` (assuming you rename the variable).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist using `$var` is however a common convention to use _when the variable is_ a jQuery object.

Comment: @Alnitak I know it is - my point is that calling it `$item1` gives the wrong impression given that he **isn't** assigning a jQuery object to it.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist he **is** assigning a jQuery object to it, now... ;-)

Comment: @AnthonyGrist forgot the $(...) but my first intention when writing this was to retrieve the jquery object... from there the OP can decide if he wants a full jquery object or just the id.